# How to return collection instead array from DB Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If to use basic queries using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` we get result as array instead collection. How to return collection?

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

It returns array of `$users` (rows).

Comment: Just wrap this in `collect()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your array of results using `collect()` should do it

```
collect($users);
```